# Modify complicated character vector automatically

Tags: r, function, vector, character

I have a complicated character vector, whereby each element of the vector consists of numbers and letters. I want to simplify this vector, so that sequences of numbers and/or letters are put into ranges. Here is an example, how the input and output vectors should look like:

```
# Input vector
input_vec <- c("1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,5,6,7,8", "2,3,4,5", "A,B,C", "1,2,3,4,5,A,B,8,9,10,11")

# Here some function should be applied, to create the desired output vector automatically

# Desired output vector
output_vec <- c("1-5", "1-3,5-8", "2-5", "A-C", "1-5,A-B,8-11")
```

I am sure there must be a way to build a function or to use a package, to do this in an automatized way, but unfortunately I am struggling to find a solution. Any help is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE: Added an even more complicated vector**

```
input_vec2 <- c("1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,5,6,7,8", "2,3,4,5", "A,B,C", "1,2,3,4,5,A,B,8,9,10,11", 
"1", "1,2,3,-4", "lala,3") # This part is new

output_vec2 <- c("1-5", "1-3,5-8", "2-5", "A-C", "1-5,A-B,8-11",
"1", "1-3,-4", "lala,3") # This part is new
```

Comment: Can LETTERS also be `A, B, C, K, L, M` which will need to become `A-C, K-M`?

Comment: Hi Sotos, yes they can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a bit bloated still, but I tried to break the problem down into smaller functions. Here they are. First some general helper functions

```
# Is value numeric?
is_numeric <- function(x) suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(x)))
# Greate IDs for sequences of values using run-length encoding
rleg <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x);
  val <- list(group_value = r$values)
  r$values <- seq_along(r$values); 
  val$group_id <- inverse.rle(r)
  val
}
```

And now some more specific helpers for the problem

```
collapse_sequence <- function(x) {
  if (length(x)>1) {
    paste0(x[1],"-", x[length(x)])
  } else {
    x
  }
}

find_runs <- function(x, key=x) {
  nona <- function(x) {x[is.na(x)]<-0; x}
  run <- cumsum(nona(c(1,diff(key)))!=1)
  Map(collapse_sequence, split(x, run))
}

collapse_numeric <- function(x) {
  paste(sapply(find_runs(x, as.numeric(x)), collapse_sequence), collapse=",")
}

collapse_character <- function(x) {
  key <- sapply(x, function(z) ifelse(nchar(z)==1, utf8ToInt(z), NA))
  paste(sapply(find_runs(x, key), collapse_sequence), collapse=",")
}

collapse_runs <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]
  type <- ifelse(is_numeric(x), 1, ifelse(nchar(x)==1, 2, 3))
  group <- rleg(type)
  runs <- Map(function(v, type) {
    if(type==1) {
      collapse_numeric(v)
    } else {
      collapse_character(v)
    }
  },split(x, group$group_id), group$group_value)
  paste(runs, collapse=",")  
})
```

And finally we test it with your input

```
input_vec <- c("1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,5,6,7,8", "2,3,4,5", "A,B,C", "1,2,3,4,5,A,B,8,9,10,11")
unname(collapse_runs(input_vec))
# [1] "1-5"          "1-3,5-8"      "2-5"          "A-C"          "1-5,A-B,8-11"
input_vec2 <- c("1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,5,6,7,8", "2,3,4,5", "A,B,C", "1,2,3,4,5,A,B,8,9,10,11", "1", 
            "1,2,3,-4", "lala,3")
unname(collapse_runs(input_vec2))
# [1] "1-5"          "1-3,5-8"      "2-5"          "A-C"          "1-5,A-B,8-11"
# [6] "1"            "1-3,-4"       "lala,3"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code @ MrFlick! For my example your code worked perfectly fine, but unfortunately I have some words in my vectors (See "lala" in example vector 2 above). Is there a way to adjust your functions, so that they are able to handle whole words?

Comment: I've updated the code to accommodate that situation. But you really should make sure when you first ask the question that your data represents your real problem as closely as possible. It's not polite to change the question after it's been answered.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the update. That really helped me a lot. Also, I want to apologize, I really did not want to be impolite in any way. With my first example, I tried to replicate my problem as good as possible and didnt realize that the additional cases would cause further problems. I will definitely avoid such situations in future.